# Raspberry Pi startx not running on boot unless su is used

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, raspbian

Startx is not running on boot on my raspberry pi 3. OS type listed below Suddenly happened after unplugging frozen pi. Startx will work when I use a non-serialized connection(running from monitor) but i have to type into the command line.

I did get startx to run on boot by adding sudo startx at the end of etc/rc.local, but it always starts the GUI as root and not the user.

I even tried using su -l pi -c startx in its place so it will run as user "pi" but it does not run at boot like sudo startx does.

---

> *PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)" NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux" VERSION_ID="9" VERSION="9 (stretch)" ID=raspbian
> ID_LIKE=debian HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
> SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
> BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"*

---

Comment: When i try to use su -l pi -c startx in the command line it prompts me for a password. Which i assume is why i wont work in the rc.local file

Comment: Have you done 'sudo raspi-config' and tried to reset the boot setting